# How I can create a list of items that grows horizontally and has horizontal scroll?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

This is my code:

```css
.wrap-here {
 display: flex;
 gap: 5px;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 width: 250px;
 overflow: auto;
}

.item {
flex: 0 0 20%;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 10px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-here">
   <div class="item">item</div>
   <div class="item">item</div>
   <div class="item">item</div>
   <div class="item">item</div>
   <div class="item">item</div>
   <div class="item">item</div>
   <div class="item">item</div>
   <div class="item">item</div>
   <div class="item">item</div>
   <div class="item">item</div>
   <div class="item">item</div>
   <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
```

Instead of what I have, I'd like the flexbox to set a limit to 2 rows of maximum wrap, and it would keep adding items horizontally, like in the following picture: [image: a table grid with 2 rows and a scrollbar for horizontal movement]

Comment: I think you can use width of the item like calc(100% / number_of_items_want_to_show_each_rows). In this you have to make minus the number of size want make for column gap. as example .item {width: calc(100% / 5 - 10px) }

Comment: I don't think that's what I want. I'd only like to set a maximum of rows that the `.wrap-here` could wrap, and then, keep adding but the items would only go horizontally instead vertically (like it normally would) @BelalKhan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is achievable with `flexbox`. I'd highly recommend doing this in `grid` for much better layout control.

#### Explanation

`flexbox` [is for one dimensional layouts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox), while `grid` [is for two dimensional layouts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout).
Yes, `flex-wrap` will make multiple rows, but you can't control the layout as you want to. The problem with `flex-wrap` in this scenario is that when applied, it won't cause any overflow, as `flex-wrap` is used to wrap the items to **prevent** overflow.

#### The solution

Since you specified the size with `width: 250px` I'm going to assume you always want 2 rows.
By applying `grid-auto-flow: column`, the layout will continuously make a new column for each item.

With `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr`, there will always be 2 rows in the layout.

With `grid-auto-columns: 20%`, each item will be a column taking up `20%` of the width of `250px`, which is `50px` (which is, from what I understand, your preferred size as you specificed `flex-basis: 20%`).

By applying `overflow-x: auto`, there will be a horizontal scrollbar from the content overflowing from the `250px` container.

```css
.wrap-here {
  display: grid;
  gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-columns: 20%;
  width: 250px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-here">
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That completely solved it! So, is it only possible with grid?

Comment: @manjirosano I updated the answer with an explanation as to why `flexbox` doesn't work for this layout :)